# Using GPUImage to extract frames from video

Tags: gpuimage

I am using GPUImage, and would like to extract a few frames from the video feed [GPUImageVideoCamera] and save as images to review when a button is clicked.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the current frame from the filter you are using.

UIImage *currentVideoFrame = [filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];